# Use vlookup with partial string match

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a number of sentences I would to apply a category automatically by partially matching a key word that leads to the category.

A spreadsheet that describes the problem is available in there https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YSxgkDhsgtSO7zKwH5u1nsvtpE_lhSoS3xN7OQaf934/edit?usp=sharing

[image]

I would like to a update the column **Category by Partial Match** by matching the first keyword from **Partial Match** column. Values in **Expected Category** is what I expect to the formula result with.

Is there any formula or combination of formulas that can achieve going trough all **Partial Match** column and then pick up  correct **Category**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*You may try:*

```js
=map(A15:A,lambda(Σ,if(Σ="",,xlookup(ifna(regexextract(Σ,textjoin("|",1,E2:E))),E2:E,F2:F,))))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, the solution works cool. I am just wondering why we have `map` and `lambda` in there? I managed to manipulate the formula and just `=if(A15="",,xlookup(ifna(regexextract(A15,textjoin("|",1,$F$2:F))),$F$2:F,$G$2:G,))` seems to do the same job.

Comment: Well its a choice if you wish to use a single *array-style* formula (`formula added in Cell_E15 of your test sheet`) **OR** a drag-style formula you showcased in your comment

Comment: @rockinfreakshow : You need to use `$E2:E` else for row 3, your formula will become `E3:E` which is wrong. So with use of `$E2:E` means whatever is row position, you are going to vlookup from `E2:E`. Same applies for `$F2:F`

Comment: @FahimParker Absolute referencing a range(*adding $ symbol before column*) is **NOT NECESSARY** for the above submitted map/lambda formula. It's an array-style formula and will be only added to the top cell(check cell E15 of the test sheet). And $ will only be added and necessary incase its a formula which needs to be dragged down across all the output cells, like in B15:B20

Answer (score 1):

Apply below formula in B16

```
=map(A15,lambda(Σ,if(Σ="",,xlookup(ifna(regexextract(Σ,textjoin("|",1,$E$2:E))),$E$2:E,$F$2:F,))))
```

Excel is updated with the same.

Comment: Thanks, I upvoted this solution but let me accept other one since the other was just first. Thanks for your input again.

Comment: sure, no issues...